# How can i add textview above an image in a scollview?

Tags: java, android, scrollview

I'm need to place a textView above a scrollView that have a background image. But i try to place the textView and it moves to other sid or doesn't move with the scroll.

here is my xml.

```
    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >


        <LinearLayout
            android:gravity="top"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageViewObrazekGeometrie"
                android:layout_width="500dp"
                android:layout_height="777dp"
                android:paddingRight="120dp"
                android:src="@drawable/dataviewer" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="TextView" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

I really don't understand your question correctly but will share where you are going wrong. A scroll view can only hold one child but in your case, your HorizontalScrollView has two children one is LinearLayout and another one is TextView please insert both to one parent layout.

Answer (score 0):

ScrollView inside another ScrollView does not work, you should place ScrollView as root and then LinearLayout as direct child of ScrollView

Comment: give orientation to your linearlayout

Comment: I only found vertical and horizontal layout, or what orientation do you refer?

Comment: Cool! is working but i can't move the textView when is inside the layout, do i have to something else?

Comment: Every view will be scrollable as long as it is inside the linear layout, under scrollview